# Find a basis and dimension of $W=\{p\in \mathcal{P}_3\,|\,p(1)=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

There are given the following linear subspaces:
$$U=\{p\in \mathcal{P}_3\,|\,p(0)=0\},$$
$$W=\{p\in \mathcal{P}_3\,|\,p(1)=0\},$$
where $\mathcal P_{3}$ denotes a space of polynomials ($n\leq 3$).

First of all, consider $U$. Every polynomial $p$ from $U$ has to be of a form 
$$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx.$$ Hence, it is easy to discover that the basis of $U$ would be $B(U)=\{x,x^2,x^3\}$. Naturally, dim(U)=3. Now, consider $W$. Take any $p\in \mathcal{P_3}$. Then 
$$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx^2+d.$$
Note that $p(1)=0$ if and only if $a+b+c+d=1$, whence $d=-a-b-c$. So, every polynomial from $W$ is of a form 
$$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx-a-b-c.$$
I thought that $B(W)=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$, but $p(x)=1$, does not belong to $W$. What would be the basis of $W$ and $U\cap W$?

Comment: Maybe $B(W)=\{(x-1), (x-1)^2, (x-1)^3\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for W

$$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx-a-b-c=a(x^3-1)+b(x^2-1)+c(x-1)$$

For the intersection $U\cap W$
 $$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2-(a+b)x \implies p(x)=a(x^3-x)+b(x^2-x)$$

Comment: What is left is the intesection. But, $p\in W\cap U$ if and only if $d=0$ and $d=-a-b-c$. From the latter, $c=-a-b$. Hence every polynomial from $W\cap U$ is of a form $$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2-ax-bx$$. Now, the question is of the basis.

Comment: For the intersection $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2-(a+b)x$ and then $p(x)=a(x^3-x)+b(x^2-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal P_3$ has dimension $4$.  With the restriction $p(1)=0$, we expect $3$ dimensions.

$p(1)=0\iff(x-1)\mid p(x).$

So for $W$, $\{x-1,x^2-x,x^3-x^2\}$ should be a basis.

And for $U\cap W$, how about $\{x^3-x^2,x^2-x\}.$  (It's clear that it's at least one dimension less.)